# Multiple displays won't say extend these displays

Tags: multiple-monitors

I have a Bravia and a Fujitsu a series. I want to setup a dual screen but the screen resolution  display setting multiple display does not give the option of extend this display, it only allows me to display desktop on either 1 or 2. I've connected them with an HDMI cable.

Any ideas on how to fix this or at least find the problem?

Its a Intel(R) HD graphics family. 
Video driver is dated 2011/04/15. 
  I went to device manager, display adapter and tried to update the drive software, windows says  it"s up to date

Comment: What graphic card do you have?

Comment: Sounds like the (correct) video drivers may not be installed.